# How to compare textfield.text and coredata attribute?

Tags: core-data, compare, textfield

Here is my code..

NSLog(@"%@", [textField text]);
NsLog(@"%@", entity.attribute);

The log shows me The values

123 and 123 as the correct values..

But this code is not works

If([textField text] == entity.attribute)     NSLog(@"Correct!");

The log "Correct!" is not shown..

What's the problem?? Help plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing NSString* pointers, not their values... they are different objects.

If both are non-nil (might want to check for that), the following will work:

```
If([[textField text] compare:entity.attribute]==NSOrderedSame) NSLog(@"Correct!");
```